# Attempting to preg_split a large, multiline file into an array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-split

I have a file formatted as...

#### file.txt

```
[sectionone]
...
...
[sectiontwo]
...
...
[sectionthree]
...
...
```

The format is very similar to (for those familiar) smb.conf and I was hoping to have an array "section" strings by the end of it. In the end I'm looking to do a preg_split to take each section of text and put in into an array like so...

```
Array
(
    [0] => [sectionone]
           ...
           ...
    [1] => [sectiontwo]
           ...
           ...
    [2] => [sectionthree]
           ...
           ...
)
```

I know I could read the file line by line and create a solution that way but I'm stubborn as hell and trying to figure this out as it suits my needs. **The split must occur when a '[' (bracket) is at the beginning of any line and anything leading up to the next bracket (newlines, tabs, any characters, etc) is fair game.** Most of my attempts have either resulted in nothing or an array count of 1 with EVERYTHING.

```
 $fileString = file_get_contents( '/tmp/file.txt' );
 print_r( preg_split( "/^\[.*\]\n$/", $fileString );
```

...results in the undesired...

```
Array
(
    [0] => [sectionone]
           ...
           ...
           [sectiontwo]
           ...
           ...
           [sectionthree]
           ...
           ...
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as my regex skills are beginner at best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need only the section names? or you need the values in each section also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps use `preg_match_all` instead?

```
$fileString = '[sectionone]
...
...
[sectiontwo]
...
...
[sectionthree]
...
...';
preg_match_all("/^\[.*?(?=\n\[|\z)/ms", $fileString, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This will match `[` till it finds a `\n` followed by a `[` or at the end of the string. The flags `ms` are important here to make `^` match the beginning of all lines and for `.` to match newlines.

Or with splitting...

```
print_r(preg_split("/\n(?=\[)/", $fileString));
```

This will match a `\n` only if followed by a `[`.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using the [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/parse_ini_file) or the [`parse_ini_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php) function, which already parses a file in the same format as `smb.conf` into an array with the configuration items.

For example, given the following config `sample.ini` (example from [parse_ini_file() docs](http://php.net/parse_ini_file)):

```
[first_section]
one = 1
five = 5
animal = BIRD

[second_section]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"
```

The following code:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini", true);
print_r($ini_array);
```

will produce:

```
Array
(
    [first_section] => Array
        (
            [one] => 1
            [five] => 5
            [animal] => Dodo bird
        )

    [second_section] => Array
        (
            [path] => /usr/local/bin
            [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
        )
)
```

Comment: First off I appreciate the response. Already went down that road and it requires a very strict format. In my case, unfortunately, between the section headers can be any number of horrid text, special characters, etc... not just x equals y. All I know for sure is the sections will start with the bracket.

Comment: Good suggestion but he said it is *similar* so if it's not the same then he would have to change his format so that it is the *exact same*.

Comment: @Evan Ouch! Yeah, in that case you're better with a custom parser.

Comment: @bluegman991 Yes, I did notice that, that's why I said to consider it -- the question wasn't clear if it had been tried. =)

Comment: @Evan Try using: `preg_split("/^\[[^[]+\]\n$/", $fileString )` -- I think the `.*` is matching the last `]` greedily.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `^` and the `$` from your regex.

This is causing the php to only match an opening bracket at the beginning of the string and a closing bracket at the end of the string.

```
$fileString = file_get_contents( '/tmp/file.txt' );
print_r( preg_split( "/\[.*\]\r?\n/", $fileString );
```

Something like this should work better for you.

Comment: Totally works, however, the headers themselves are missing. I do appreciate the solution though as I may use it elsewhere.